# How to create a group with chef

Tags: chef

I assume this is straightforward, but I'm lost in the abstractions in Chef. I want to create a new Unix group on Red Hat Linux, called deployers, and then add some of my users to that group. What are the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [group](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_group.html) LWRP:

```
group "mygroup"
```

In order to add members, you can list them:

```
group "mygroup" do
  members "member1"
end
```